# Property of isomorphic normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two normal subgroups of given $G$ group and $A \cong B$. I'm wondering how to prove that $\phi(A)\cong B$ where $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that an automorphism is an isomorphism of $G$. If you restrict the domain of $\phi$ to $A$, it is still bijective with its image; so you have a bijective homomorphism between $A$ and $\phi(A)$. Since $A \cong B$ by assumption, we have $\phi(A) \cong A \cong B$.

Comment: Mike, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is ambiguous. For instance, perhaps you are wondering "how to prove that there exists $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ such that $\phi(A) \cong B$''. It is quite possible that no such automorphism exists, for instance $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $A=2\mathbb{Z}$, $B=3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: As it is written, this question must be interpreted the way you do. Unfortunately when our understanding is murky, we often can’t even express our questions clearly.

Comment: @Lubin I disagree that it *must* be interpreted this way. Lee Mosher is right - it is ambiguous, and so either interpretation is correct. On the other hand, I agree wholeheartedly with the sentiment of your second sentence.

Comment: $\phi$ the identity map always works for $\phi(A) \cong B$. Probably this answer meant to say there need not be a $\phi$ with $\phi(A) = B$.